# How can I keep track of when videos get a large number of views?

Tags: youtube, analytics

I monetize my Youtube videos, but to avoid annoying my regular subscribers I set my video defaults to disable the "TrueView" ads (the video ads) but enable the less-annoying overlay ads on new videos. My plan is I'll use less annoying ads on the majority of the videos so I don't annoy my subscribers, but on very popular videos I'll enable the TrueView ads since A) that's where the money is anyway and B) most of my "regulars" have already seen the view without the extra annoyance.

So I'd like to know when videos reach a threshold of say 1000 views. For now I've been glancing at the Video Manager page to see if any large view counts pop up, but old videos rapidly pop off the first page. I have a large number of videos over 1000 views already, so the "most viewed" page also isn't useful for seeing which *new* posts have hit over 1000 views.

How can I most easily track which videos have recently gotten over 1000 views or at least which videos are recently abnormally popular, ideally with Youtube's included analytics/pages on Youtube itself? The "Top Ten Videos" part of the Overview section in Analytics isn't super helpful either, as it contains many old but still popular posts.

Answer (score 1):

I just made [YouTube Views Count Notification](http://www.thelacunablog.com/notification-youtube-views-increases.html) spreadsheet to address this. It sends you an email whenever the views count crosses the threshold set by you. I noticed just now that the question is two months old. So, if you are still looking for a solution, this might be of help to you.

How it works :

1. User enters a list of video ID on a column.
2. Use of [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries) to grab the views/title of each video.
3. List views/title on separate columns.
4. Check the column to determine if the views is greater than a user
   specified threshold (for ex. 1000 like you said).
5. If the above condition is true, send an email with the title, url
   and views count of the video.
6. Remove the video ID from the column.

I hope it helps. Thanks.